# java code to build a path

Tags: java

I was trying to make a code that will take input from a user and prints out the file path. I came across a interesting example. But I got stuck understanding a line.

```
//gets input from the user
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
String request = input.readLine();
String path = new String(); 

int start = 0;
int end = 0;

for (int a = 0; a < request.length(); a++) {
    if (request.charAt(a) == ' ' && start != 0) {
        end = a;
        break;
    } 
    if (request.charAt(a) == ' ' && start == 0) {
        start = a;
    }
}

path = request.substring(start + 2, end);
```

Why is a 2 is added at the end?

Comment: maybe it truncates the hard-drive letter ? - "C:"

Comment: Apparently they don't want any of the user input until two characters after the first whitespace if there's spaces in the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The java `File` class does most anything you need.  What are you actually trying to do?  What is the input?  What kind of output are you looking for?

---

Per your comment, if you have a file in the working path called `index.html`, then you could:

```
File file = new File( "./index.html" );
System.out.println( file.getAbsolutePath() );
```

There is another method of the file class called `getCanonicalPath()` which may also be useful.

Comment: what i'm trying to do lets say i client sends a get method for index.html file. i'm trying to view the absolute path of that file.

Comment: @user1052462, you would probably get a better response if you explain what you are trying to do in the first place.  Then you likely would not have gotten voted down...

Comment: @Lucas..thanks for your advice and help..I'll keep it in mind next time.